# how to get the search function to filter fragments within a listview

Tags: android, listview, search, android-fragments

Having issues trying to get the search function to filter the fragments within a listview. I am using ActionBarSherlock following this tutorial:  http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-search-collapsible-view-in-android/ . I have the search function/search button located on the MainActivity.java as of now. I've tried moving it to the fragment, as it shows from the turtorial, but it doesn't display in the actionbar.

**Editt**: Added Populate.java & NavListAdapter.java code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
// Declare Variables
NavListAdapter adapter;
EditText editsearch;
String[] title;
String[] subtitle;
Fragment fragment1 = new FiveHundred();
Fragment fragment2 = new OneThousand();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Generate title
title = new String[] { "Title Fragment 1", "Title Fragment 2" };

// Generate subtitle
subtitle = new String[] { "Subtitle Fragment 1", "Subtitle Fragment 2" };


// Pass results to NavListAdapter Class
adapter = new NavListAdapter(this, title, subtitle);

// Hide the ActionBar Title
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

// Create the Navigation List in your ActionBar
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

// Listen to navigation list clicks
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navlistener = new OnNavigationListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment2);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        return true;
    }

};
// Set the NavListAdapter into the ActionBar Navigation
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navlistener);
}

// Create the options menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Get the options menu view from menu.xml in menu folder
getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_layout, menu);

// Locate the EditText in menu.xml
editsearch = (EditText) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();

// Capture Text in EditText
editsearch.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

// Show the search menu item in menu.xml
MenuItem menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

menuSearch.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

    // Menu Action Collapse
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        // Empty EditText to remove text filtering
        editsearch.setText("");
        editsearch.clearFocus();
        return true;
    }

    // Menu Action Expand
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        // Focus on EditText
        editsearch.requestFocus();

        // Force the keyboard to show on EditText focus
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        return true;
    }
});

return true;
}

// EditText TextWatcher
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
            .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    adapter.filter(text);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

};
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Populate> populatelist = null;
private ArrayList<Populate> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Populate> populatelist) 
{
mContext = context;
this.populatelist = populatelist;
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Populate>();
this.arraylist.addAll(populatelist);
}

public class ViewHolder 
{
TextView Name;
TextView Value;

}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return populatelist.size();
}

@Override
public Populate getItem(int position) 
{
    return populatelist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
} 

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) 
{
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
    holder.Value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Value);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else 
{

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
// Set the results into TextViews
holder.Name.setText(populatelist.get(position).getName());
holder.Value.setText(populatelist.get(position).getValue());     

// Listen for ListView Item Click
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);
        // Pass all data errorName
        intent.putExtra("Name",(populatelist.get(position).getName()));
        // Pass all data errorCode
        intent.putExtra("Value",(populatelist.get(position).getValue()));
        // Start SingleItemView Class
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }

});
    return convertView;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) 
{
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    populatelist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) 
{
    populatelist.addAll(arraylist);
}
else
{
    for (Populate p : arraylist)
    {
        // Search filter code
        if (p.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
        {
            populatelist.add(p);
        }
        else if (p.getValue().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
        {
            populatelist.add(p);
        }
    }

}       
notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

FiveHundred.java

```
public class FiveHundred extends SherlockFragment
{
// Declare Variables
ListView list;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
EditText editsearch;
String[] Name;
String[] Value;

ArrayList<Populate> arraylist = new ArrayList<Populate>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_main, container, false);
     return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
     arraylist.clear();
     super.onStart();

// Generate sample data
Name = new String[] 
        { 
            // 0-10
            "A name goes here!!", "Mother", "Father" 
        };

Value = new String[] 
        { 
            // 0-10
            "A value goes here!!", "1", "2"
        };


// Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

for (int i = 0; i < Name.length; i++)
{
    Populate p = new Populate(Name[i], Value[i]);
    // Binds all Strings into an array
    arraylist.add(p);
}

// Pass results to ListViewAdapter.class
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

// Binds the adapter to the ListView
list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Populate.java

```
public class Populate 
{
private String Name;
private String Value;

public Populate(String Name, String Value) 
{
this.Name = Name;
this.Value = Value;
}

public String getName() 
{
return this.Name;
}

   public String getValue() 
   {
     return this.Value;
   }
   }
```

NavListAdapter.java

```
public class NavListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
String[] mTitle;
String[] mSubTitle;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public NavListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] subtitle) {
this.context = context;
this.mTitle = title;
this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTitle.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mTitle[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// Declare Variables
TextView txtTitle;
TextView txtSubTitle;

inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_list_item, parent, false);

// Locate the TextViews in nav_list_item.xml
txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

// Set the results into TextViews
txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);
txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);
return itemView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// Declare Variables
TextView txtTitle;
TextView txtSubTitle;

inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View dropdownView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_dropdown_item, parent,
        false);

// Locate the TextViews in nav_dropdown_item.xml
txtTitle = (TextView) dropdownView.findViewById(R.id.title);
txtSubTitle = (TextView) dropdownView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

// Set the results into TextViews
txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);
txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);

return dropdownView;
}

public void filter(String text) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: post the code of `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`

Comment: @Mehul Joisar The FiveHunred.java is Fragment1. OneThousand(Fragment2) has the same code, but the data strings dispaly different text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside `onCreate` or `onCreateView` of your both fragments.

**Reference:**
[setHasOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu%28boolean%29)

You also need to implement the override of `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside your both fragments.

```
   @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_layout, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: I tried the code that you had suggested but it created 2 sets of the search button in action bar. I had also tried moving everyting from public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) from the MainActivity.java and add it to the fragments to remedy that issue, but it was still not filtering the list. Would have any other suggestions that I might try? Thanks